# Web pagination with JdbcTemplate and Oracle 11g / H2 without scrollable resultset

Tags: java, oracle11g, jsp-tags, jdbctemplate

This must have been done a thousand times but I can't find the Java code online.

I'm coding a web page that shows a list from Oracle 11g, retrieved by a Dao using JdbcTemplate.

It's essentially an audit log, with a search field for date to show log entries from that date and previous.

My audit log service class will call the Dao and limit the number of rows returned to 100, and has to work out the latest date to specify on the query. Then it will pass back a list of audit log javabeans to the MVC layer.

This is my best effort for the SQL, which has to be H2 (Oracle mode) compatible as well for testing purposes. (That rules out the row_number() function). latestDate and maxRows are the params.

```
    SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT * FROM T_ETL_AUDIT_LOG 
                WHERE LOG_TIMESTAMP  < ?latestDate 
            ) WHERE rownum < ?maxRows;
```

So I need to work out what the parameters on the web page are going to be (e.g. lastDate, previous, next), and the audit log service algorithm has to handle the first call (with date=Now), and previous page, next page without getting confused.

I haven't searched for a pagination tag for the JSP yet so any suggestions would be cool but that's icing on the cake.

NB I am not using Oracle 12 so I can't utilise the new Oracle pagination functionality

2015-01-20 - just changed the title to exclude scrollable resultset solutions.

Comment: Well you should try first..starting with pagination is no rocket science, and if you get stuck then you can come back here with some code to show.

Comment: You might want to be aware that your SQL will not work if your data set can have a LOG_TIMESTAMP at the exact same time.  Using the < operation could mean you skip rows

Comment: @Bartdude you're making me sound lazy. I've been looking at it for a while and even while trying to come up with a suite of tests for TDD just makes me thing, this has got to be basic functionality, why am I spending time re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: @MrWiggles I was thinking of rounding the date up to exactly 23:59:59.999 of the day and providing a simple date picker.

Comment: That works if you pull out all the data for an entire day, but if you want to limit your pagesize and need to fetch subsequent data you could end up missing records.

Comment: @MrWiggles you mean if two dates have exactly the same timestamp down to the millisecond, the first makes it into the limited set, the second doesn't? OK, edge case - I can try `<=`

Comment: <= also doesn't work as it will pull back the record you've already sent back, you need a secondary key for your sorting- an auto-incrementing number works well here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using page numbers on the client-side, so the 'next' and 'previous' buttons transmit the next or previous page number. My service translates the page number into the previousLastRow and the lastRow parameters for the DAO. The original search date remains the same on every page until the user changes it.

This is the SQL for Oracle, with the parameters substituted in for page 2 (i.e. rows 101 to 200):

```
select * from (
    select ROWNUM as row_num, b.* from (
        select ROWNUM, MY_TIMESTAMP 
        from T_MY_TABLE 
        where MY_TIMESTAMP < TIMESTAMP'2015-01-20 12:12:34'
        and ROWNUM <= 200
        order by MY_TIMESTAMP desc
    ) b 
) where row_num > 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

JDBCTemplate does not directly help with pagination. You must make the query to deal with page number and page size. Also a query for the count should be done.

This is a solution where pagination components have been created one by one: http://javablackboard.blogspot.ro/2013/05/jsp_7.html

Here a custom jsp tag is used for pagination: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072877/swing-gui-programming/paging-long-lists.html

Comment: Thanks for replying but I'm using Oracle 11g, so I can't use the MySQL offset and limit format SQL. I also can't take the 'greedy' approach you mention which retrieves all the rows from the table into a RS. The second article your blog links to is more like what I need to do. There are so many articles like that out there, but not one specifically for this situation.

Comment: There has to be a reason for not creating a scrollable query so you should think  that through.  A scrollable query will solve the problem and those are fully supported by JDBC.  You can fetch the number of rows per page you need, in each page generation loop, until you exhaust the record set.

Comment: Using a scrollable resultset in Oracle for what could get really big is not a good idea. The data is cached client-side, not in the DB: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm It could cause out-of-memory errors in the JVM.